# Replace path of the working directory to UNC path

Tags: windows, batch-file, forfiles

I have a scripts which outputs all subfolders which name starts with a predefined value. Because I need it to work on a network location, I use PushD. All works well and the output matches the requested search criteria. However, the current output displays the location on the temp location, and not the full path on the netwerk path. How can I modify the script to display the correct full network location, and not the location on temp folder? Can I do a search and replace?

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
PushD %arg1% &&(
forfiles /s /m %arg2%* /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @path"
) & PopD
```

so when running 
    c:\test.bat "\\server\folder" DEMO

will output ...

```
z:\folder\DEMO_project 1
```

and not ...

```
\\server\folder\DEMO_project 1
```

How can I fix this? Thanx...

Comment: It will assign a drive letter for you to use similarly to `net use * \\..` . you could just get the UNC path of the drive letter.. for instance if you move away from using `forfiles` make some changes, then you could collect the drive letter and replace with path.. as an example: `for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('net use ^| findstr /i Z:') do echo %%i`

Answer (score 0):

As you already know that the UNC path is `\\server\folder`, is there any reason why you're not returning `@RelPath` instead?

```bat
@If "%~2"=="" Exit /B 
@PushD "%~1" 2>NUL&&(
    ForFiles /M "%~2*" /S /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==TRUE Echo @RelPath"
)&PopD&Pause
```

*In this case the returned output would look a little more like this `.\folder\DEMO_project 1`.*

---

If you really need to prepend with the known UNC, an additional round of parsing could be used to substitute the leading period with your known string:

```bat
@If "%~2"=="" Exit /B
@PushD "%~1" 2>NUL&&(
    ForFiles /M "%~2*" /S /C "Cmd /Q/C If @IsDir==TRUE For /F \"Tokens=*Delims=.\" %%A In (@RelPath)Do Echo %~1%%~A"
)&PopD&Pause
```

*This example would return output a little more like this, `\\server\folder\folder\DEMO_project 1`*

---

Please note that I have posted complete [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) examples in full replacement of your posted code, they do not need any modification!

Answer (score 0):

The [`prompt` command](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) can display the network path in case the drive points to such, though unfortunately there is a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> returned. Anyway, this could be made use of as in the following:

```cmd
@echo off
pushd "%~1" && (
    forfiles /S /M "%~2*" /C "cmd /Q /C if @isdir==TRUE for /F 0x22tokens=1-3 delims=/0x22 %%A in ('prompt $P\/$M^& for %%z in ^(@relpath^) do rem/%%~z') do if 0x22%%B0x22==0x22rem0x22 (for %%z in (@path) do echo(%%~z) else set 0x22SH=%%B/.\%%~pA rem/%%C0x22 & cmd /V /C echo(!SH: rem/.\=!"
    popd
)
```

To explain the code behind the `/C` option of the [`forfiles` command](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) it is resolved in a way to have code blocks and that `0x22` is replaced by `"`; see all the additionally inserted explanatory `rem` remarks:

```cmd
rem // Execute the following code only when the current item is a directory:
if @isdir==TRUE (
    rem // Capture the following command echo string:
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%A in ('
        rem/ Set the prompt string, then use a `for` loop that iterates once, ^^
        rem/ executes `rem` with the relative path of the current item and ^^
        rem/ just echos this with the prompt string preceded: ^& ^^
        prompt $P\/$M^& for %%z in ^(@relpath^) do rem/%%~z
    ') do (
        rem // The second token is just `rem` in case we have a local path:
        if "%%B"=="rem" (
            rem /* Simply echo the full path of the local path, but with the surrounding
            rem    quotation marks removed by a `for` loop and the `~` modifier: */
            for %%z in (@path) do echo(%%~z
        ) else (
            rem /* For a network path, we need to build the absolute UNC path by joining
            rem    the captured network path from the echo string, the path relative to
            rem    the drive mapped by `pushd` and the relative path from `forfiles`;
            rem // since the echo string also contains the echoed command `rem` itself,
            rem    let us smartly assemble a string that requires only one replacement: */
            set "SH=%%B/.\%%~pA rem/%%C"
            rem /* Echo the build absolute network path with two removals of ` rem/.\`;
            rem    enable delayed expansion at this point to avoid losses of `!`: */
            cmd /V /C echo(!SH: rem/.\=!
        )
    )
)
```

[Delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is necessary to modify and gather the variable `SH` in the same line of code.

[Sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is then used to remove artefacts coming from echoing the command `rem`.

---

To explain in detail how the code works, let us assume a few example situations and take a look at the command echo with the preceding prompt string and how it is split and joined then:

1. the current path `D:\` is local and there is one matching sub-item `Sub`:

   - the prompt is `D:\\/` and the echo is `rem/.\Sub`, so `for /F` receives to parse:

     ```cmd
     D:\\/rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - `for /F` splits it into the three tokens `D:\\` (`%A`) and `rem` (`%B`) and `.\Sub` (`%C`);
   - the second token is just `rem`, so simply return the absolute path with surrounding quotation marks removed:

     ```cmd
     D:\Sub
     ```
2. the current path `D:\Data\Test` is local and there is one matching sub-item `Sub`:

   - the prompt is `D:\Data\Test\/` and the echo is `rem/.\Sub`, so `for /F` receives to parse:

     ```cmd
     D:\Data\Test\/rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - `for /F` splits it into the three tokens `D:\Data\Test\` (`%A`) and `rem` (`%B`) and `.\Sub` (`%C`);
   - the second token is just `rem`, so simply return the absolute path with surrounding quotation marks removed:

     ```cmd
     D:\Data\Test\Sub
     ```
3. the current path `Z:\` is a network path where drive `Z:` points to the remote location `\\SERVER\Share`, and there is one matching sub-item `Sub`:

   - the prompt is `Z:\\/\\SERVER\Share` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and the echo is `rem/.\Sub`, so `for /F` receives to parse:

     ```cmd
     Z:\\/\\SERVER\Share rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - `for /F` splits it into the three tokens `Z:\\` (`%A`) and `\\SERVER\Share rem` (`%B`) and `.\Sub` (`%C`);
   - the second token is NOT just `rem`, so append `/.\`, then the first token with the drive `Z:` removed (hence `\` as the used `~p` modifier resolves `\\` to `\`), then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `rem/`, then the third token, so we get this string:

     ```cmd
     \\SERVER\Share rem/.\\ rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - after removal of both instances of the sub-string <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `rem/.\` we finally get:

     ```cmd
     \\SERVER\Share\Sub
     ```
4. the current path `Z:\Test` is a network path where drive `Z:` points to the remote location `\\SERVER\Share`, and there is one matching sub-item `Sub`:

   - the prompt is `Z:\Test\/\\SERVER\Share` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and the echo is `rem/.\Sub`, so `for /F` receives to parse:

     ```cmd
     Z:\Test\/\\SERVER\Share rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - `for /F` splits it into the three tokens `Z:\Test\` (`%A`) and `\\SERVER\Share rem` (`%B`) and `.\Sub` (`%C`);
   - the second token is NOT just `rem`, so append `/.\`, then the first token with the drive `Z:` removed (hence `\Test\`), then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `rem/`, then the third token, so we get this string:

     ```cmd
     \\SERVER\Share rem/.\\Test\ rem/.\Sub
     ```
   - after removal of both instances of the sub-string <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `rem/.\` we finally get:

     ```cmd
     \\SERVER\Share\Test\Sub
     ```